# How to convert Yaxis of seaborn countplot to reflect percent values?

Tags: python, seaborn

I have used seaborn countplot to analyse voting pattern in different sub-areas(categories), under column `areaName` of dataframe `dh`.

```
sns.countplot(x=dh['areaName'],hue='Target',data=dh)
plt.xlim(1,7)
```

Output:

[image: output]

How do I convert the count on y-axis of Graph to percentages?
To be more specific, I'd like the y-axis to represent percent values from, 0-100,

Then for each sub-area(for eg:`Hunegallu`), to show the Hue categories(got by using `hue='Target'`, as shown in code) in percent not in, count-values. Say for Eq, in Graph below for subarea `Hunegallu` in X-axis, `hue='Target'` has given me 3 colors,that is blue,orange,green and let's say here their respective approx count values are 8,4,2. Therefore, in percent terms blue is 8/14 which is approx 57 percent, orange is 4/14 which is approx 28 percent, then green is 2/14 which is approx 14 percent.

Similarly, I'd like percent values on y-axis for `hue='Target'`, on each subarea on x-axis.

Answer (score 1):

The above code snippet is from https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1027 .

```
df = sns.load_dataset("tips")
x, y, hue = "day", "prop", "sex"
hue_order = ["Male", "Female"]

f, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2)
sns.countplot(x=dh['areaName'], hue='Target', data=dh)

prop_df = (dh['areaName']
           .groupby(df['Target'])
           .value_counts(normalize=True)
           .rename(y)
           .reset_index())

sns.barplot(x=dh['areaName'], hue='Target', data=dh)
```

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'.......i got this error

Comment: @ravsab551955  could you please share the sample dataframe ?

Comment: could u pls send me ur email id , so that i can mail u , that sample, thankyou